# SurveyJS.io in display mode showing user answer and correct answer in quiz

Tags: surveyjs

I am new to SurveyJS and have been able to integrate surveys and quizzes into my website. This is my use-case. After a user has completed a quiz, as standard practice user sees the number of correct and incorrect answers. Later, I would like the user to browse through the questions showing the correct answer with the user answer (in case it is different). Ideally, by changing the color. What would be the best manner to provide this functionality? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `showPreviewBeforeComplete` option will help you. Here is the documentation link - https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Library?id=surveymodel#showPreviewBeforeComplete